# PHP Variable to JQuery function?

Tags: php, jquery

I need a relative path in this function:

```
    $(function() {
            $("#searchbox").autocomplete({
                    minLength : 2,
        source    : function (request, response){
                                $.ajax({
                                    url      : "http://linux/project/index.php/main/search/",
                                    dataType : "json",
                                    data     : { key : request.term},
                                    type     : "POST",
                                    success  : function(data){
                                    response($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.original_name,
                            value: item.original_name,
                                                            id   : item.project_id+"/"+item.folder_id+"/"+item.id
                        }
                    }))

                                           }
                            })
                            },
                    select : function(event, ui) {
                                document.location.href = "http://linux/project/index.php/projects/loaddocument/"+ui.item.id;
                             }

    });
});
```

How can I use a PHP Variable path to replace http://linux/project in the function above?

Best regards ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
url : "http://<?php echo $path; ?>/index.php/main/search/"
```

Or, if the script is in a separate .js file, something like this:

```
// in the main page
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var config = { basePath : '<?php echo $path; ?>' };
</script>

// in the .js file
url : "http://" + config.basePath + "/index.php/main/search/"
```

Comment: Simple and efficient. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

is there an efficient way to serialize the translation of the dayNamesMin and monthNames, or did I have to do this for each item?:

```
        $(function() {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat  : 'dd.mm.yy',
                showWeek    : true,
                firstDay    : 1,
                weekHeader  : 'KW',
                dayNamesMin : ['So','Mo','Di','Mi','Do','Fr','Sa'],
                monthNames  : ['Januar','Februar','März','April',
                               'Mai','Juni','Juli','August','September',
                               'Oktober','November','Dezember'],
                onSelect    : function(dateText,inst){
                              }
            });
});
```